# Caching content from URLs based on ETag header

Tags: r, json, caching, httr

I'm working on scraping content from over 1000s URLs using httr and jsonlite. Currently I retrieve the list of webpage IDs from the "tournaments" page and then create a list of URLs which I loop through using lapply. This gives me a list of JSON objects. This takes over 6 minutes to retrieve the content from the complete set of URLs.

```
tournaments <- GET("http://listfortress.com/api/v1/tournaments/")
tournaments <- fromJSON(rawToChar(tournaments$content))
tournaments

#Generating list of tournament urls
urls <- paste0("http://listfortress.com/api/v1/tournaments/", tournaments$id)

#Scraping urls
data <- lapply(urls, GET)
```

However, the vast majority of these pages don't receive any new content or updates once recorded. I'd like to speed up this process by caching the data that has been unmodified and only overwriting the content for pages that have been modified.

The API for these pages does not contain a "Last-Modified" header, but it does contain an "ETag" header which I understand records whether content has been modified.

What I'm not sure how to do is use the ETag header to only retrieve information from modified pages and then update my dataset with those pages (dropping the old data from those pages).

Comment: The etag will change when the document has changed. You'll need to store the last etag for each page. It doesn't look like the server supports the "If-None-Match" so you'll still have to make GET (or HEAD) calls to each URL to get the current etag to see if it's changed.

Comment: @MrFlick. Thanks! Will that practically speed up my requests since I still have to make the calls to each URL?

Comment: If you only send a HEAD() request you won't have to wait for the content to transfer. But if the bodies are small, that won't make much of a difference. You'd have to test it to see if it makes any practical difference in your application. It likely won't be much faster as far as network stuff goes, but it would make it easier for you to know if you have to parse the contents to update your local store.

Comment: Yeah I tested and calling HEAD is almost exactly the same in terms of time. Is it usually possible for the API administrator to add "If-None-Match" as a header?

Comment: Well, to support a header like that you've need some infrastructure for caching and invalidating the cache. I have no idea how that particular website is run. If they have tech support for the API then you should contact them.

Comment: I think it's just one guy running the website as a hobby, so it might be a longshot. Thanks for the info though.